# Is there a portable alternative to registerDoMC?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multicore

I initially set `doMC::registerDoMC(...)` but then realized it doesn't work on windows and thought that maybe it wasn't actually needed since I only need for parallel processing the following functions which don't state anything about `doMC` in their documentation:

```
parallel::mclapply(..., mc.cores = ncores)
caret::train(..., trControl = trainControl(..., allowParallel=T))
```

However, to my surprise everything runs single-cored without `doMC::registerDoMC(...)`

Is there a portable way to replace `doMC::registerDoMC(...)` with?

**UPDATE**

In Ubuntu 18.04 with R 3.6.x having:

```
ncores <- parallel::detectCores()
```

If I replace this:

```
if(!require(doMC)) install.packages("doMC")
registerDoMC(ncores)

caret::train(..., trControl = trainControl(..., allowParallel=T))
```

with that:

```
if(!require(doParallel)) install.packages("doParallel")
cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoParallel(cl, ncores)

caret::train(..., trControl = trainControl(..., allowParallel=T))

stopImplicitCluster()
```

Then `caret::train` crashes after 2 seconds

```
Aggregating results
Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:
      RMSE        Rsquared        MAE     
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :162   NA's   :162   NA's   :162  
Error: Stopping
In addition: Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

Comment: check the future (and futurexxx) package(s), otherwise doParallel

Comment: FYI, it's either `doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = cluster)` or `doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = n)`.  Note, they give you two completetly different parallelization backends!  ... unless on MS Windows, where the latter becomes the former variant internally.

Comment: `cl` is a mandatory argument, this is why I had to create the `cl` clusters .. what ever happened to simplicity :D

Comment: That's not correct; it _is_ either `cl` or `cores` and _not_ both.  What makes you believe it is mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm the author)

Try the [doFuture](https://cran.r-project.org/package=doFuture) foreach backend;

```
doFuture::registerDoFuture()
future::plan("multisession")
```

I run all of [caret](https://cran.r-project.org/package=caret) examples with different future parallel backends as part of doFuture's validation tests.  This far they all pass with doFuture (https://travis-ci.org/HenrikBengtsson/doFuture) which suggests that the future framework managed to automagically identify all globals that needs to be exported to the background workers.  This is not true for, say, [doParallel(cl = cluster)](https://cran.r-project.org/package=doParallel) - I think the main reason is that the parallelization in caret was (only?) tested with multicore-like backend where globals "just work", e.g. [doMC](https://cran.r-project.org/package=doMC).

Comment: Great! thanks! how about `mclapply`? I don't want to rewrite my code ... would I need to?

Comment: So, AFAIU, this part is a bit off topic since the above is about 'caret' which relies on 'foreach' internally.  Having said that, you should be able to replace `parallel::mclapply()` with `future.apply::future_lapply()` calls.  The latter will then use whatever parallel backend you've specified in `future::plan(...)`.